# Extracting fields from .csv file input line

Tags: java, arrays, csv, split

I'm very new to the world of Java programming, and although I know this is a ridiculously easy question, I can't seem to phrase my searches in a way that turns up the answer I need...so hopefully someone from this community won't mind helping me.

MY program needs to take an input line from a .csv file and split it into fields of an array, using commas as delimiters. The fields of the array are then assigned to variables that are different data types - char, int, float, and string.  What I'm struggling with is the formatting for my String variables.

Here is part of my code:

```
public void parseCSV(String inputLine) {

String[] splitFields;
splitFields = inputLine.split(",");

try {
    empNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitFIelds[0[);
    payType = splitFields[1].charAt(0);
    hourlyRate = Float.parseFloat(splitFields[2]);
    last name =
```

I need to assign variable lastName, a String data type, to position 3 of my splitFields array. I just don't know how to format it. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

### A warning on your overall approach

Go with the other answers if you're doing a homework assignment with a simple csv file, but splitting a String on the comma character `,` will *not* work for more complicated CSVs. Example:

```
"Roberts, John", Chicago
```

This should be read as *two* cells where the first string is `Roberts, John`. Naive splitting on `,` will read this as *three* cells: `"Roberts`, `John"`, and `Chicago`.

### What you should be doing (for robust code)

If you're writing serious/production level code, you should use the [Apache Commons CSV library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) to parse CSVs. There are enough tricky issues with commas and quotations, enough variation in possible formats that it makes sense to use a mature library. There's no reason to reinvent the wheel.

### Another tool for parsing text

If you're a beginner, this might be opening up a can of worms, but a powerful tool for parsing/validating text input is "regular expressions." Regular expressions can be used to match a string against a pattern and to extract portions of a string. Once you have extracted a String from a specific cell of a csv, you could use a regular expression to validate that the String is in the format you're expecting.

While you're unlikely to really need regular expressions for this project, I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I will definitely keep regular expressions and the Apache Commons CSV library in mind for future projects. Being a self-professed noob, I haven't really reached that level yet, but it's good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`String.split(...)` returns a `String[]` so you really can just assign a specific index to a `String`.

```
String s = "one two dog!";
String[] sa = s.split(" ");
String ns = sa[1]; // ns now equals "two"
```

so you can just:

```
last_name = splitFields[index]; // this will work fine as long as index is within the `array` bounds.
```

**Please mind that your `last name` var has a space(that might have been you problem).**

I also recommend minding the parses, `Integer.parseInt(...)` & `Float.parseFloat(...)` might `throw` a `NumberFormatException` if you try to parse a non decimal values.

Comment: The space was just a typo - it appears as lastName in my program. Thank you for catching that, though. :) I've just been learning about exceptions and I have a try...catch in place to hopefully catch those. Thanks!

Comment: you should check out @MatthewGunn answer he has an important point there.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, it is already a `String`, so you do not have to perform additional parsing. The following assignment will do the trick:

```
lastName = splitFields[3];
```

Comment: I knew it wouldn't be a complicated answer - it was just irritating to not know. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!